# adding boxplot outliers after specifying quantiles

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, outliers, quantile

I need to create a custom boxplot in R, which uses the quantiles 0.05, 0.20, 0.50, 0.80 and 0.95 that make up the box and whiskers, rather than the default.

The default plot was generated using this code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(Site, LOG10Val)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

and looks like this:
[image]

To specify the custom bounds of the boxplots, the code I used was:

```
ggplot(data, aes(Site, LOG10Val)) + 
  stat_summary(geom = "boxplot", 
               fun.data = function(x) setNames(quantile(x, c(0.05, 0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 0.95)), 
                                               c("ymin", "lower", "middle", "upper", "ymax")), 
               position = "dodge")
```

the plot becomes:

[image: custom plot]

Is there a way to reintroduce the outliers (ie >95th percentile) into the custom boxplot?

Thanks.

Edit: my data structure is as follows:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  Date       Site  Analyte      Value LOG10Val
  <date>     <fct> <fct>        <dbl>    <dbl>
1 2014-01-10 E     Ammonia_mg.L 0.02     -1.70
2 2014-01-10 C     Ammonia_mg.L 0.01     -2   
3 2014-01-10 D     Ammonia_mg.L 0.015    -1.82
4 2014-01-31 E     Ammonia_mg.L 0.01     -2   
5 2014-01-31 C     Ammonia_mg.L 0.01     -2   
6 2014-01-31 D     Ammonia_mg.L 0.01     -2
```

Comment: Could you give us an example of your data using `dput`

Comment: I've included my data structure in my question above @neuron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to add the outliers via a second `stat_summary` layer.

Making use of `iris` as example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  stat_summary(
    geom = "boxplot",
    fun.data = function(x) {
      setNames(
        quantile(x, c(0.05, 0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 0.95)),
        c("ymin", "lower", "middle", "upper", "ymax")
      )
    }
  ) +
  stat_summary(geom = "point", fun = function(x) {
    outlier_high <- x > quantile(x, .95)
    outlier_low <- x < quantile(x, .05)
    ifelse(outlier_high | outlier_low, x, NA)
  }, na.rm = TRUE)
```

[image]